# Using Bootstrap's intended form validation styles

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am interested in using the Bootstrap form validation styles documented at http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#validation.

When I paste the exact HTML for this first example on my own site, the colors/styles are off, and the glyphicons are not present (not sure if glyphicons are intended to appear by default in these types of fields, or if that was just specific to the example page). See image below:

[**Same exact code from Bootstrap site running on my site**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2w1y5.png)

As you can see, the danger color on my site isn't even registering at all (both field and checkboxes have default colors instead of red).

Is there something I'm missing here? This seems like such a dumb issue, but I can't find any answers. I have no CSS overriding this, and the example pictured was taken from an otherwise blank HTML doc. I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.6 from their CDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bootstrap doc website that you linked is for the alpha version of Bootstrap 4, not 3. Download Bootstrap version 4 or have a look at these v3 docs: [Bootstrap - Validation States](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation)